# Excel field needs to return a null or na

Tags: excel-2010

I have the following formula in excel `=COUNTIF('Doc Dec 2013'!M28:M67,"R")` , it works fine and returns the values it should, however what i need to do is get it to return an N/A or something similar  when it has a 0, to stop it showing on a chart till the data is there. I tried adding a IF to the start of it but it just errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Doc Dec 2013'!M28:M67,"R") > 0,COUNTIF('Doc Dec 2013'!M28:M67,"R"), "N/A")
```